To remove intermedite Page like signup page when login with linkedin
In settings.py file
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid_connect',

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google":{
        "SCOPE":[
            "profile",
            "email"
        ],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {"access_type": "online"},
        "EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION": True,
    },
    
    "openid_connect": {
        "APPS": [
            {
                "provider_id": "linkedin_oidc",
                "name": "hrms",
                "client_id": os.environ.get("linkdin_id"),
                "secret": os.environ.get("linkdin_secret"),
                "settings": {
                    "server_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth",
                    "token_auth_method": "client_secret_post",
                    "scope": ["openid", "email"]
                },
            }
        ]
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
    
)
SITE_ID = 4

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = "login"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'


When I complete login with linkedin then page redirect to http://localhost:8000/accounts/social/signup/ url, If anyone know how to remove this intermediate page and redirect to my dashboard page
In Login template
{% load socialaccount %}
<div class="social-auth-links text-center mb-3">
        <p>- OR -</p>
        <form action="/accounts/oidc/linkedin_oidc/login/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
          <i class="fab fab fab fa-linkedin mr-2"></i> Sign in using Linkedin
        </button>
        </form><br>
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">
          <i class="fab fa-google-plus mr-2"></i> Sign in using Google+
        </a>
      </div>

